# HashMap Is Not Storing Information Input

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, methods, hashmap

I cant get the User information to be stored into the `HashMap` of the `User` class. Going off of the current code below, it only stores one input at a time but as soon as I enter new information it is removed. See screen shots of the results below

Main Class:
Passes the information to the `User` Class within the Main class

```
// Creates account window: creates account
       else if (e.getSource() == createB){
                  createB.setFocusable(false); // removes the border around create button
                  firstName = fNameTF.getText().trim();
                  middleName = mNameTF.getText().trim();
                  lastName = lNameTF.getText().trim();
                  department = depTF.getText().trim();
                  passWord = passTF.getText().trim();
                 
                  if(firstName.isBlank() || middleName.isBlank() || lastName.isBlank() || department.isBlank() || passWord.isBlank()){
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Fill Out All Boxes ","ATTENTION",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE );
                  }
                  else if (passWord.length()< 8 ){
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Enter More Than 8 Characters For Password ","ATTENTION",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE );
                      
                  }
                  else{  
                      userInformation = new User (firstName, middleName, lastName, department, passWord);  
                    try{ 
                        userInformation.storeUserInfo();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User Account Created! ","STATUS",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
                        fNameTF.setText(" ");
                        mNameTF.setText(" ");
                        lNameTF.setText(" ");
                        depTF.setText(" ");
                        passTF.setText(" ");
                        }
                    catch(RuntimeException  ex){
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Could not create account, please try again","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
                        }   
                  }
       }
```

User Class method that stores the information into the HASMAP

```
    // Method to store the user's informatino like Firstname, LastName,etc...
    public void storeUserInfo (){
        userID = iDCount.incrementAndGet();
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList("UserID:"+userID));
        System.out.println("before"+ userRecord);
        this.userRecord.put(userID,getFirstName()+getMiddleName()+getLastName()+getDepartment()+getPassword());
        System.out.println("after" + userRecord);
     
    }
   
}
```

Screen Shot: [Entry of User Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgHWC.png)

Main CLass

```
public class Email_GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    // Fields
    // Labels
    private JLabel fNameL = new JLabel ("First Name:");
    private JLabel mNameL = new JLabel ("Middle:");
    private JLabel lNameL = new JLabel ("Last Name:");
    private JLabel depL = new JLabel ("Department:");
    private JLabel passL = new JLabel ("Password (at least 8 characters):");
    private JLabel centerB = new JLabel("Welcome!, please make a selection", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    private JLabel idlabel = new JLabel ("ID:");
    //Jbutton
    private JButton createB = new JButton ("Create");
    private JButton createUB = new JButton ("Create Account");
    private JButton viewUB = new JButton ("Search Account");
    private JButton cancelB = new JButton ("Cancel");
    private JButton searchB = new JButton ("Search");
    //JTextFIeld
    private JTextField fNameTF = new JTextField (20);
    private JTextField lNameTF = new JTextField (20);                     // Fields
    private JTextField mNameTF = new JTextField (20);
    private JTextField depTF = new JTextField (20);
    private JTextField passTF = new JTextField (20);
    private JTextField iDTF = new JTextField (20);
    private JTextField resultTF = new JTextField (80);
    
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private String department;
    private String passWord;
    //JPanel & container for Main GUI
    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel vMiddlePanel = new JPanel ();
    JPanel searchPanel = new JPanel ();
    Container mainContainer;
    //Access USer Class
    User userInformation;
    // Window identifier
    int wIdentifier = 0;
    Color customColor = new Color (226,135,67); // Custom color for Navigation menu

    // GUI 
    public Email_GUI  () {
        super("Administrator");
        this.setSize(700, 450);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        mainContainer = this.getContentPane();
        mainContainer.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        mainContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout(8,6));
        this.getRootPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(4, 4, 4, 4, Color.LIGHT_GRAY));
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 2, true);
        TitledBorder tBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(border, " Navigation Menu   ");
        Border eBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(6, 6, 6, 6);
        CompoundBorder cBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(tBorder, eBorder);

        //Panel Left
        leftPanel = new JPanel();
        leftPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
        leftPanel.setBorder(cBorder);
        leftPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(3,0)));
        leftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        leftPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        leftPanel.add(createUB);                                          //Left Panel that hosues the create and search accounts
        createUB.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 35));
        createUB.setFocusable(false);
        leftPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
        leftPanel.add(viewUB);
        viewUB.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(350, 35));
        viewUB.setFocusable(false);
        mainContainer.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        
        //Panel Middle
        centerB.setOpaque(true);
        mainContainer.add(centerB);
        centerB.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        centerB.setVisible(true);                                   // Displays "Welcome!, please make a selection" in the middle of window 
        createB.addActionListener(this);
        createUB.addActionListener(this);
        viewUB.addActionListener(this);
        cancelB.addActionListener(this);
        searchB.addActionListener(this);
    }
    @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){            // in charge of all actions performed when buttons are pressed
       // Create account window
       if(e.getSource()== createUB){
            wIdentifier = 1;
            createUB.setEnabled(false);
            viewUB.removeActionListener(this);
            centerB.setVisible(false);
            Border lBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1);
            Border eBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(80, 30, 5, 30);
            CompoundBorder cBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(lBorder, eBorder);
            Border tFStyleRB = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
            Border tFStyleLB = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
            Border tFBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(tFStyleRB,tFStyleLB);
            middlePanel = new JPanel();
            middlePanel.setBorder(cBorder);
            middlePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 2, 1, 3));
            middlePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            middlePanel.setVisible(true);
            middlePanel.add(fNameL);
            middlePanel.add(fNameTF);
            fNameTF.setBorder(tFBorder);
            fNameTF.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
            middlePanel.add(mNameL);
            middlePanel.add(mNameTF);
            mNameTF.setBorder(tFBorder);
            mNameTF.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,20));
            middlePanel.add(lNameL);
            middlePanel.add(lNameTF);
            lNameTF.setBorder(tFBorder);
            lNameTF.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,20));
            middlePanel.add(depL);
            middlePanel.add(depTF);
            depTF.setBorder(tFBorder);
            depTF.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
            middlePanel.add(passL);
            middlePanel.add(passTF);
            passTF.setBorder(tFBorder);
            passTF.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
            middlePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalBox());
            middlePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalBox());
            middlePanel.add(createB);
            middlePanel.add(cancelB);
            middlePanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(60));
            mainContainer.add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);  
            
        }
       //Create account window: Cancel account
       else if (e.getSource() == cancelB){
           int dialogButton= JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Are you sure?","WARNING",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                  if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                      if(wIdentifier == 1){
                        fNameTF.setText(" ");
                        mNameTF.setText(" ");
                        lNameTF.setText(" ");
                        depTF.setText(" ");
                        passTF.setText(" ");          // closes out the Create account window if "YES" is selected
                       createUB.setEnabled(true);
                       viewUB.addActionListener(this);
                       centerB.setVisible(true);
                       remove(middlePanel); 
                      }
                      else if(wIdentifier == 2){
                        fNameTF.setText(" ");
                        mNameTF.setText(" ");
                        lNameTF.setText(" ");
                        depTF.setText(" ");          // Closes out the Search account window if "YES" is selected
                        iDTF.setText(" ");
                        viewUB.setEnabled(true);
                        createUB.addActionListener(this);
                        centerB.setVisible(true);
                        remove(vMiddlePanel); 
                        remove(searchPanel);
                      }
                  } 
                  else {
                      if(wIdentifier == 1){                  // keeps create account window open if "NO" is selected
                          middlePanel.setVisible(true);
                      }                                        
                      else if (wIdentifier ==2 ){              // keeps search account window open if "NO" is selected
                          vMiddlePanel.setVisible(true);
                      }
                  } 
       }
       // Creates account window: creates account
       else if (e.getSource() == createB){
                  createB.setFocusable(false); // removes the border around create button
                  firstName = fNameTF.getText().trim();
                  middleName = mNameTF.getText().trim();
                  lastName = lNameTF.getText().trim();
                  department = depTF.getText().trim();
                  passWord = passTF.getText().trim();
                 
                  if(firstName.isBlank() || middleName.isBlank() || lastName.isBlank() || department.isBlank() || passWord.isBlank()){
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Fill Out All Boxes ","ATTENTION",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE );
                  }
                  else if (passWord.length()< 8 ){
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Enter More Than 8 Characters For Password ","ATTENTION",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE );
                      
                  }
                  else{  
                      userInformation = new User (firstName, middleName, lastName, department, passWord);  
                    try{ 
                        userInformation.storeUserInfo();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User Account Created! ","STATUS",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
                        fNameTF.setText(" ");
                        mNameTF.setText(" ");
                        lNameTF.setText(" ");
                        depTF.setText(" ");
                        passTF.setText(" ");
                        }
                    catch(RuntimeException  ex){
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Could not create account, please try again","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
                        }   
                  }
       }
       // View account window
       else if (e.getSource()== viewUB){
           wIdentifier = 2;
           createUB.removeActionListener(this);
           viewUB.setEnabled(false);
           centerB.setVisible(false);
           MatteBorder border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
           TitledBorder tBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(border, " Search ");
           Border eBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(8, 20, 4, 20);
           CompoundBorder cBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(tBorder, eBorder);
           Border tFStyleRB = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
           Border tFStyleLB = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
           Border tFBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(tFStyleRB,tFStyleLB);
           vMiddlePanel = new JPanel();
           vMiddlePanel.setBorder(cBorder);
           vMiddlePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 2, 1, 3));
           vMiddlePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
           vMiddlePanel.setVisible(true);
           vMiddlePanel.add(fNameL);
           vMiddlePanel.add(fNameTF);
           fNameTF.setBorder(tFBorder);
           fNameTF.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
           vMiddlePanel.add(mNameL);
           vMiddlePanel.add(mNameTF);
           mNameTF.setBorder(tFBorder);
           mNameTF.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,20));
           vMiddlePanel.add(lNameL);
           vMiddlePanel.add(lNameTF);
           lNameTF.setBorder(tFBorder);
           lNameTF.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100,20));
           vMiddlePanel.add(depL);
           vMiddlePanel.add(depTF);
           depTF.setBorder(tFBorder);
           depTF.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
           vMiddlePanel.add(idlabel);
           vMiddlePanel.add(iDTF);
           iDTF.setBorder(tFBorder);
           iDTF.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
           vMiddlePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalBox());
           vMiddlePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalBox());
           vMiddlePanel.add(searchB);
           vMiddlePanel.add(cancelB);
           mainContainer.add(vMiddlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
           MatteBorder rborder = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
           TitledBorder rTBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(rborder, " Results ");
           Border rEBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(6, 3, 2, 2);
           CompoundBorder rCBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(rTBorder, rEBorder);
           searchPanel = new JPanel();
           searchPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 120));
           searchPanel.setLayout(new CardLayout());
           searchPanel.setBorder(rCBorder);
           searchPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
           searchPanel.setVisible(true);
           searchPanel.add(resultTF);
           resultTF.setSize(10, 15);
           resultTF.setBorder(tFBorder);
           resultTF.setEditable(false);
           resultTF.setBackground(Color.white);
           mainContainer.add(searchPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
         
       }
       else if (e.getSource() == searchB){
           searchB.setFocusable(false); // removes the border around create button
           String firstName = fNameTF.getText().trim();
           String middleName = mNameTF.getText().trim();
           String lastName = lNameTF.getText().trim();
           String department = depTF.getText().trim();
           String passWord = passTF.getText().trim();
           if(userInformation.userRecord.containsValue(firstName)){
              resultTF.setText(userInformation.userRecord.get(firstName));
           }
           

           
       }
    }

    
    

    
public static void main(String[] args){
    Email_GUI GUI = new Email_GUI ();
    
    
    
            }
}
```

User Class

```
public class  User {
    //Fields
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String middleName;
    private String department;
    private String password;
    private  int userID;
    private static final AtomicInteger iDCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public HashMap<Integer, String> userRecord = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
 
    //Constructor that processe user information
    public User (String fName,String mName, String lName, String depart, String pass){
        this.firstName = fName;
        this.middleName = mName;
        this.lastName = lName;
        this.department = depart;
        this.password = pass;            
    }
    
     public void setFirstName( String firstN){
         this.firstName = firstN;
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList("FirstName:"+firstName));
        
    }
    public void setMiddleName(String middleN){
        this.middleName = middleN;
         System.out.println(Arrays.asList("MiddleName:"+middleName));
        
    }
    
    public void setLastName(String lastN){
        this.lastName = lastN;
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList("LastName:"+lastName));
        
    }
    
    public void getDepartment(String dep){
        this.department = dep;
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList("Department:"+department));
        
    }
    public void setPassword(String pass){
        this.password = pass;
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList("Password:"+password));
        
    }
    
    public void setID (int iDent){
        this.userID = iDent;
    }
   
    // get methods
    public String getFirstName(){
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList("FirstName:"+firstName));
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getMiddleName(){
         System.out.println(Arrays.asList("MiddleName:"+middleName));
        return middleName;
    }
    
    public String getLastName(){
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList("LastName:"+lastName));
        return lastName;
    }
    
    public String getDepartment(){
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList("Department:"+department));
        return department;
    }
    public String getPassword(){
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList("Password:"+password));
        return password;
    }
    public int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }
    
    // Method to store the user's informatino like Firstname, LastName,etc...
    public void storeUserInfo (){
        userID = iDCount.incrementAndGet();
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList("UserID:"+userID));
        System.out.println("before"+ userRecord);
        this.userRecord.put(userID,getFirstName()+getMiddleName()+getLastName()+getDepartment()+getPassword());
        System.out.println("after" + userRecord);
     
    }
    
    
    

  
    
            
     
   
    
    
}
```

Comment: In your question, why do you shout HashMap and User at us? Anybody who could help you could easily recognize their names when properly capitalized.

Comment: Whenever you use `userInformation = new User(...)` you are completely overriding/replacing the existing `userInformation` object  which contained your `userRecord` HashMap. To solve this you need to move the `userRecord` HashMap to the Main class, or you need to stop creating a new user object and create an add/insert method, for example `userInformation.add(firstName, middleName, lastName, department, passWord);`

Comment: It’s much code for a Stack Overflow question. To increase chances that people read your questions considerably you should train how to create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `userRecord` should be `static`. There is no sense in having one collection of users per user.